# jQuery submit() doesn't include submitted button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have one form that has several elements and two submit buttons, one is "Save" the other is "Delete". On the "Delete" button I am using jQuery dialog to confirm user wants to delete. Then if they confirm, I submit the form. The problem is jQuery.submit() doesn't include the original submit button when it is posted so I can't distinguish on the server a Delete from a Save since they are both using the same form. If I remove the jQuery dialog then the submit button value is posted as expected. This HAS to be very common and I am hoping someone can share a solution. I've searched around and can't find anything useful (is it just me or is google sucking lately?)

Thanks for any help...

**EDIT:**

The submit buttons do have names and values set. It works fine if don't use jQuery.submit()

Comment: Incorporate ID's on your submit buttons to distinguish between Save/Delete in your jQuery/server side checks

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the issue. I have values for the submit buttons. It works fine when I don't use jquery.submit().

Comment: This problem exists with the `serialize()` method too, despite the submit buttons having all the usually attributes set, they won't be recognised. I had to manually handle them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on karim79's answer:

```
$("input[type=submit], input[type=button], button").click(function(e) {
    var self= $(this),
        form = self.closest(form),
        tempElement = $("<input type='hidden'/>");

    // clone the important parts of the button used to submit the form.
    tempElement
        .attr("name", this.name)
        .val(self.val())
        .appendTo(form);

    // boom shakalaka!
    form.submit();

    // we don't want our temp element cluttering up the DOM, do we?
    tempElement.remove();

    // prevent default since we are already submitting the button's form.
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

UPDATE:

I just realized the above code is probably not what you are looking for:

If you are calling submit on the form element itself (`$("form").submit();`) you will need something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $("input[type=submit], input[type=button], button", form).eq(0).each(function(){
        var self= $(this),
            tempElement = $("<input type='hidden'/>");

        // clone the important parts of the button used to submit the form.
        tempElement
            .attr("name", this.name)
            .val(self.val())
            .appendTo(form);
    });
});
```

Which will add the *first* button element's name and value to the DOM right before the form is submitted (I'm not sure what the default browser behavior is here). Note that this doesn't remove the `tempElement` from the DOM. If there is an error and the form isn't submitted the element will remain and you will have problems if you don't take care of this.

Comment: Looks good, I will give this a try. Appreciate the help...sometimes the easiest things...

Comment: can you do a request.getParameter() on the server side to get the button values

Comment: jQuery's `submit` doesn't include the button values.

Answer (score 3):

The submit button data is only submitted if it is clicked on. So you would also be out of luck if somebody pressed enter instead of clicking on the submit button.

I strongly recommend to remove the delete-button from the form, as it probably won't need most of the form's information anyway (only the ID of the data record you want to delete), change it to a button (with `type="button"`) that submits a different form or, if you can, put a link there. (That links to a delete page - this is better for usability reasons anyway, because it removes the focus from the delete-option and reduces the risk of your users accidentially clicking on the delete button.)

Comment: good ideas. I tried going the different form route by handling click and submitting different form but ran into some issues with trying to make this generalized. Since I have a dialog, I was using  (this).closest("form"), then submitting. This worked great if the button was contained in its own form. But once included with standard form it didn't work as it was submitting the wrong form. 

Re: putting delete on a different page. That makes sense to me, but users won't go for it in this case. They want to avoid extra step.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should have the delete function on a different page. You can and should have it on the same page, just outside the form, or using a link (that would redirect the user to a page that performs the deletion).
What was your problem with "generalization"? (I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that.)

Comment: What I mean by generalizing is I have a centralized place that handles the delete confirmation and then submitting of the form. So in a general.js file I hook up the click event for buttons that have a deleteConfirmation class. I moved the button into its own form and I am trying to use CSS to line it up next to the other buttons

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is can be resolved by incorporating an 'action' parameter somehow, which tells the server what the purpose of the submission is. For example, assuming your form is submitted via GET:

```
$("form :input").click(function() {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var submitTo = $form.attr("action") + '?action=' + $(this).val();
    alert(submitTo);
    // window.location.href = submitTo;
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/JT3GV/5/

Comment: I am submitting via post. Does that matter?

Comment: Why not add a hidden input element with the same `name` as the "clicked" input button right before submitting the form? Then remove the hidden input after it has been submitted. That way the form will work the same for non-js and js submissions and will work the same when using GET or POST.

Comment: @David Murdoch - Good suggestion. I was initially going post something along those lines - I opted to provide a simple example to demonstrate that an extra parameter can be used, without going into too much detail.

Comment: I added an answer with my recommendation.  :-)