# $("#form").submit() doesnt send the name of the pressed button through

Tags: php, jquery

I have a long form, that's a sliding page form so that it is broken up into parts for the user.

I do my error checking through jQuery, here is the code:

```
$("input.next").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var stage = ((($("#container").position().left) / 950) * -1) + 1;
        var thispage = $(this).closest("div.page");
            var errors = false;
            var isFinal = $(this).hasClass("send");

            thispage.find("input.txt").each(function () {
                if(($(this).val() == "") && (!$(this).hasClass("optional"))) {
                $(this).css("background","#FFE5E5");
                errors = true;
            } else {
                $(this).css("background","#E5FFEA");
            }
        });

        thispage.find(".checkbox").each(function () {
            if(!$(this).is(':checked')) errors = true;
        });

        if(thispage.find("#profileimage").val() == "") errors = true;

        thispage.find("textarea.txt").each(function () {
                if(($(this).val() == "") && (!$(this).hasClass("optional"))) {
                $(this).css("background","#FFE5E5");
                errors = true;
            } else {
                $(this).css("background","#E5FFEA");
            }
        });

        if(!errors) {
            // if no errors, slide to next page.
            if(!isFinal) {
                thispage.find("div.errormessage").fadeOut(50);
                $("#container").animate({left: "-=950px"}, 800, function () {
                    $("ul#stages li").removeClass("active");
                    $("ul#stages li.stage"+stage).addClass("active");
                    console.log("Stage: " + stage);
                });
            }
        } else {
            thispage.find("div.errormessage").fadeIn(100);  
        }

        console.log("isFinal: " + isFinal);
        console.log("Errors: " + errors);

        if((isFinal) && (!errors)) {
            console.log("submitting form...");
            $("#enrolform").submit();               }

    });
```

However when the `div.next.send` button is pressed, it has a name of `sendapplication` and in my PHP code I am using:

`if(isset($_POST['sendapplication'])) {`

..To check whether the entire form was submitted or not.  The reason I need to do this is because I also have a 'save' feature of the form, which allows the user to save the data and come back later.

The problem is when the user clicks 'sendapplication' button I don't get that through in the $_POST or $_REQUEST variables.  And I think the reason why is because it's the jQuery script that's sending it, and not the button.  The button is suppressed because of the `e.preventDefault()` line.

How can I check that that particular button was pressed? is there someway I can manipulate the `.submit()` function?

Comment: This is a major limitation in jQuery, last I knew. The only real workaround I know of is to listen for a `click` event on the form instead of `submit`, then check if the clicked element was a submit button, add it to the form as a hidden input such as `name="button_pressed"`, perform validation and submit. Alternatively, use HTML5 validation and remove all the jQuery - much better :p

Comment: Instead of using `$("#enrolform").submit();`, this should work: `$(sendapplicationSelector).off('click').click();`

Comment: Is your `input.next` button `type="submit"`? Consider only calling `e.preventDefault()` (i.e. suppressing the submission of the form) if the validation *fails*, otherwise just let it carry on through with submitting the form.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes I was thinking about something along those lines.

Comment: Purely as an aside, you really shouldn't be doing this: `$(this).css("background","#FFE5E5");`. This is *guaranteed* to be a nightmare to maintain down the road. Your JavaScript should leave actual selection of colors up to your CSS. Instead of manually adding colors, just add classes: `$(this).addClass('with-error')` and `$(this).removeClass('with-error')`.

Comment: Sorry, i meant in previous comment: `$(this).off('click').click();` but ya, you'd have better to rethink your logic instead, using the submit event of the FORM and check for validation there

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code into the click() method:

```
var self= $(this),
form = self.closest(form),
tempElement = $("<input type='hidden'/>");

// clone the important parts of the button used to submit the form.
tempElement
   .attr("name", this.name)
   .val(self.val())
   .appendTo(form);
```

See [jQuery submit() doesn't include submitted button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605671/jquery-submit-doesnt-include-submitted-button) for more details

Anthony Grist's comment is probably a lot better solution to this :)