# Django request.data.get('submit') returns always none, even if name is provided as name="submit"

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am passing a form from my template to views, with some text inputs and a input type button as follow:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Continue">
```

But in my views when I do

```
print(request.data.get('submit_btn'))
```

It return none.
Also when I do :

```
print(request.data)
```

It return all values except the 'submit_btn'

Please HELP!

Comment: It is not `'submit'`, but `'submit_btn'`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do `request.data.get('submit_btn')` instead. Or even `request.POST.get('submit_btn')`(depending how you're doing that on your views.py) What you're looking to access is the the button/input by "name"

Comment: By your post you're trying to access `request.data.get('submit')`. Maybe you should do `request.POST.get('submit_btn')` It'd be easier to help you post your views.py

Answer (score 0):

I still did not got any solution on why this is happening but after following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605671/jquery-submit-doesnt-include-submitted-button)

I was able to solve my problem by passing a other hidden input with the same value and submit name.